# Тестирование cron скрипта Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Пытаюсь протестить cron-скрипт.

```
php -f local/cron/notify_statistic_product.php
```

В результате в консоле вижу ошибку

```
syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/www/u1304156/data/www/domain.ru/bitrix/modules/main/include/autoload.php on line 24
```

Иду в bitrix/modules/main/include/autoload.php. Вижу там:

```
use Bitrix\Main\Loader;

//main is usually included directly
$documentRoot = Loader::getDocumentRoot();
foreach(
    [
        'Bitrix\\Main' => '/bitrix/modules/main/lib',
        'Bitrix\\UI' => '/bitrix/modules/ui/lib',
        'Psr\\Container' => '/bitrix/modules/main/vendor/psr/container/src',
        'Psr\\Log' => '/bitrix/modules/main/vendor/psr/log/Psr/Log',
        'PHPMailer\\PHPMailer' => '/bitrix/modules/main/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src',
        'GeoIp2' => '/bitrix/modules/main/vendor/geoip2/geoip2/src',
        'MaxMind\\Db' => '/bitrix/modules/main/vendor/maxmind-db/reader/src/MaxMind/Db',
    ]
    as $namespace => $namespacePath
)
{
    Loader::registerNamespace($namespace, $documentRoot.$namespacePath);
}
unset($namespace, $namespacePath);

spl_autoload_register([Loader::class, 'autoLoad']);

Loader::registerAutoLoadClasses(
    'main',
    [
        'bitrix\\main\\application' => 'lib/application.php',
...
```

По сути ругается на строку

```
spl_autoload_register([Loader::class, 'autoLoad']);
```

Версия PHP 8.1. Версия Битрикс 22.600.
Если кто сталкивался или знаетк как поправить, поделитесь плиз.

Comment: Проверьте версию PHP "php -v". Возможно cron-скрипт запускаете не на 8.1

Comment: Спасибо. Да, именно в этом и была проблема.